# JavaScript in webpage not working

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have this webpage

```
<input id="show" style="display: inline;" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('hash').value = hex_sooml('M77LNALA');" value="Show Password">

<input style="display: inline;" id="hash" size="50" type="text">

<script type="text/javascript">
function hex_soom1(pass)
{
return pass;
}
</script>
```

When I click the button nothing happens. Why?

Comment: `hex_soom1` is not the same as `hex_sooml`. Also, check your Javascript console for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed _soom1 from function name and it is working:   http://jsfiddle.net/g4dboz12/

```
<input id="show" style="display: inline;" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('hash').value = hex('M77LNALA');" value="Show Password">

    <input style="display: inline;" id="hash" size="50" type="text">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hex(pass) {
            return pass;
        }
    </script>
```